# Error in Coding problem. Everything is Written But Nothing Prints

Tags: java

Nothing will print when run. Where's the error?

In this project you will simulate two games. In the first game, roll one die four times and record a "win" if a six is rolled at least once during the four rolls, otherwise record a "loss". In the second game, roll two die twenty-four times and record a "win" if two six's are rolled at least once during the twenty-four rolls, otherwise record a "loss". Your program should simulate running each game a million times and output the number of wins and losses for each game.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int win6 = 0;
        int lose6 = 0;
        int win24 = 0;
        int lose24 = 0;


        int n = 100000000;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++){
                Random r = new Random();
                int next = r.nextInt(1-6);

                if (next == 6){
                    win6 = win6 + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            lose6 = 100000000 - win6;
            for (int u = 0; u <= 24; u++){
                Random r = new Random();
                Random t = new Random();
                int next1 = r.nextInt(1-6);
                int next2 = t.nextInt(1-6);

                if (next1 == 6 && next2 == 6){
                    win24 = win24 + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            lose24 = 100000000 - win24;

        }
        System.out.println(win6);
        System.out.println(lose6);
        System.out.println(win24);
        System.out.println(lose24);

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running this? Do you get an error or just no output?

Comment: `r.nextInt(1-6);` will throw an error.

Comment: yeah I adjusted that to say r.nextInt(6-1); Still getting nothing to print though.

Comment: I am getting no output.

Comment: Are you sure the program is not just taking a long time to run? Also, you should only create one `Random` object. Also, `for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)` loops 5, not 4 times.

Comment: You'll never hit any of your break conditions and are looping 3 billion times. It's bound to take a while, especially with all the `Random` objects you're creating. The assignment calls for a million iterations, why did you go with 100 million to start off?

Comment: Introduce a constant for 100000000 (so you can change the value in one place) and run with 1000 first. Please update your question with any code changes you make.

Comment: I've figured it out now. It has been taking so long to run and now I've found that it works.